# Google+ within an iOS app

Tags: ios7, google-plus

I am trying to set Google+ to work within an iOS app I am developping. I got things set up to a certain point.
And now I see this message in the debugger:

> [GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl open] User must be signed in to use the
>   native sharebox.

I have to sign into Google+ but the question is where do I have to do that? I am not sure I get the meaning of this message.
Is it something I should do inside the app or outside?

Comment: No need to put duplicate answer so please check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981721/user-must-be-signed-in-to-use-the-native-share-box

Comment: OK thanks. I will check that.

Comment: @Michel Have you got any solution to your question? If yes then please share here as I am also facing same issue.

Comment: That was quite a while ago, so that is not at the top of my mind any more.
I probably had the issue when I was working on this app http://www.sofisfun.net/HereNow/
If you look at the app(free) and think I must be solving your problem then I will search a bit more. Otherwise it is possible that I gave up or it would also be possible the the solution was for an old version of iOS.