# User must be signed in to use the native share box

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-plus

I want to add share on google-plus property in my application.
I registered client application on google web console and obtained client-id.

In my viewDidLoad function :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    CGRect  rect = self.view.bounds;
    rect.size.height = rect.size.height - 50;
    _postContentUIWV = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [_postContentUIWV loadHTMLString:selectedPostCD.content baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:_postContentUIWV];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];




    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
   // signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // Uncomment to get the user's email

    // You previously set kClientId in the "Initialize the Google+ client" step
    signIn.clientID = kClientID;

    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                          @"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                                          @"http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity",
                                          @"http://schemas.google.com/CheckInActivity",
                                          @"http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity",
                                          @"http://schemas.google.com/CreateActivity",
                                          @"http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity",
                                          @"http://schemas.google.com/ReserveActivity",
                                          @"http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity",
                                          nil];

    // Uncomment one of these two statements for the scope you chose in the previous step
    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];  // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" scope
    //signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];            // "profile" scope

    // Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
    signIn.delegate = self;


    [signIn trySilentAuthentication];

}
```

Then in my onButtonCLick function:

```
- (void) googlePlusShareTapped {


    id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.shinnxstudios.com"]];
    [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"This is an awesome G+ Sample to share"];
    // [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Title" description:@"Descp" thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.fbo.com/imageurl"]];

    [shareBuilder open];
}
```

However I get the message:

```
 [lvl=3] -[GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl open] User must be signed in to use the native share box.
```

I downloaded google+ app from App Store and signed in. But every time I get this message and cannot share anything on google+.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you got any solution to your question? If yes then please share here as I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First remove your application from simulator then close XCode and reopen and run your app again by changing with following code:

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
    signIn.delegate = self;
    [signIn authenticate];
```

And also make sure that you have to added `GooglePlus.bundle` in to your application.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.. Every time i have to sign in and even after sign i am getting the error message

Comment: I work for me but i want to know,how we come back to home screen after completing sharing procedure?