# User must be signed in to use the native sharebox

Tags: ios, google-plus

I follow the answer  [User must be signed in to use the native share box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981721/user-must-be-signed-in-to-use-the-native-share-box) but still found an error..

Due to this

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
```

its working fine when i change

```
id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
```

Any Suggestion ????