# iOS swift native google sharing error message as user must login

Tags: ios, swift

Code:

```
 let signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
    signIn.clientID = ""
    signIn.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];
    signIn.trySilentAuthentication();
    signIn.delegate = self

    let shareDialog = GPPShare.sharedInstance().nativeShareDialog()
    shareDialog.setPrefillText("Check This out")
    shareDialog.setURLToShare(NSURL(string: "https://developers.ggoe.com/+/"))
    shareDialog.open()
```

I am trying to share content with native share dialogue.
i got error message as 
"[GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl open] User must be signed in to use the native sharebox".any help will be apprecated.thanks in advance

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981721/user-must-be-signed-in-to-use-the-native-share-box)

Answer (score 0):

Youre error message is an answer to youre question!

> [GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl open] User must be signed in to use the
>   native share box

When we read carefully we could get that you should be authenticated to perform this action.

And after you login check if user is authenticated to perform this action with method.

```
- (void) authenticate
```

Also it is recommended firstly to read [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start) about platform you are using.

From the official documentation:

> The native share dialog requires that you use Google+ Sign-In in your
>   app and ensures that your visitors stay in your app in context while
>   sharing content.

Comment: is there way to open share dialogue box with out signin?